# CLI utility to search and download YouTube videos in wav format

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, software-rec, youtube

I have a text file contains about 50 song titles.

I'm searching for a CLI utility that can take each title from the text file, search for it on YouTube, get the top 4 video links then download the audio of the link.

So far I tried with `youtube-dl`, there is a search feature there but it only returns metadata and I can't seem to find the links of video in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- WAV is not modern audio container format; not quite sure why you want a container format that only supports constant-rate and -blocksize audio codecs. But since that is a really awkward thing for a streaming service to deliver, you'll have to download the audio and transcode it to some such codec and put it in a WAV container. Luckily `yt-dlp -x --audio-format wav` does that for you. (`yt-dlp` is a fork of `youtube-dl`, haven't checked that.). Again, fix whatever you're doing with that audio if it needs WAV, rather than transcode to a codec that fits in WAV, which very often means gigabytes of uncompressed audio.
- `yt-dlp ytsearchN:Search string` will get the N top results for "Search string" (`youtube-dl` doesn't currently have that feature, you need `yt-dlp`)
- putting it all together, `ytdlp -x --audio-format wav ytsearch:YOURTERMSHERE` does what you want, for each YOURTERMSHERE search term.
- To read a full file line by line, you would just pipe it to the stdin of `yt-dlp` and use `--batch-file -`:

grabsound.sh:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
sed 's/^/ytsearch4:/' < $1 | yt-dlp --batch-file - -x --audio-format wav
```

<sub>(untested)</sub>

`chmod 755 grabsound.sh` allows you to run the program directly, and you can then just do `/path/to/grabsound.sh yourtextfile.txt`.

Again, I strongly advise you to *not* use WAV. Even if you plan to transcode to a different format later on, what you're ending up doing here is not necessary, since you'd be better and faster off just decoding the original audio on the fly instead of transcoding to (mostly uncompressed PCM) WAV.